# How can I disable warnings from non project files? --- Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, warnings, ogre

I use Ogre 3d and it is producing a great amount of warnings.

Can I disable all warnings for files which are not inside my project?

Comment: Were u able to find the pointed pragma in the ogre source, as i mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can also try;
- #pragma warning(disable : xxxx)
- Where xxxx represent the warning number i.e 4000 or 8010

Comment: the point is, Ogre throws round about 4600 different warnings because of the mentioned not matching pragmas

Answer (score 1):

use the "#pragma warning" before including the ogre3d header (guess you do it in the "stdafx.h"). [Here a link how that work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/441722ys%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a special Ogre problem, I really don't know why they don't fix it by their self.

They use a `#pragma warning pop` (or push, I'm not sure anymore) without the corresponding `#pragma warning push/pop`. You have too look for the pragma push/pop warning in the thousands of output warnings and delte it, if you then recompile ogre, the warnings should be gone. ;)

And to Answer you'r question in generell:
Usually this shouldn't happen, but for this, ogre is also a special case.

Because the code is involved to your project, so the used ogre source gets recompiled with each compilation. So your project gets effected by the ogre framework warnings too.
(This is at least the case if you set ogre up as in the setting up tutorial. But i would bet their are ways to link ogre completly)